# Suddenly, Expo SDK 48 iOS build failed in the fastlane

Tags: ios, reactjs, expo, native, fastlane

I'm trying to build an iOS app from my managed Expo project. The build is failing at the Fastlane step. I think I might have selected something wrong during the process because this started happening out of nowhere, and now I can't build iOS for any project. I'm using Windows.

```
{
    "name": "provedor",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "description": "",
    "author": "Edilson Souza",
    "scripts": {
        "app": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "clear": "expo r -c",
        "eject": "expo eject",
        "update": "expo update",
        "app:android": "eas build --platform android --profile production",
        "app:android-apk": "eas build --platform android --profile preview",
        "app:ios-sim": "eas build -p ios --profile preview",
        "app:ios": "eas build --platform ios --profile production",
        "postinstall": "patch-package",
        "submit:ios": "eas submit --platform ios",
        "submit:android": "eas submit --platform android"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
        "@hashiprobr/expo-pdf-reader": "^1.0.8",
        "@mobeuv/react-native-check-ip": "^1.3.0",
        "@react-br-forms/cpf-cnpj-mask": "^1.0.6",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
        "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
        "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.5",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.11",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
        "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
        "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
        "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
        "expo": "~48.0.4",
        "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
        "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
        "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
        "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
        "expo-checkbox": "~2.3.1",
        "expo-clipboard": "~4.1.2",
        "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
        "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
        "expo-notifications": "^0.18.1",
        "expo-permissions": "~14.1.1",
        "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.1.1",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
        "expo-system-ui": "~2.2.1",
        "firebase": "^9.22.2",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "native-base": "^3.4.26",
        "patch-package": "^7.0.0",
        "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.14",
        "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
        "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
        "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
        "react-native-input-credit-card": "^0.5.5",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.3",
        "react-native-modalize": "^2.1.1",
        "react-native-public-ip": "^1.0.2",
        "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
        "react-native-root-siblings": "^4.1.1",
        "react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
        "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
        "react-native-webview": "11.26.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
        "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.0.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

Here is fastlane error

```
› Compiling react-native-safe-area-context Pods/react-native-safe-area-context » RNCSafeAreaViewManager.m
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Provedor' from project 'Provedor')
    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Provedor' from project 'Provedor')
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Provedor-eenohjajhyzizocoocnasrhbuisp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Provedor/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00016A70.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
▸ (1 failure)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Provedor-eenohjajhyzizocoocnasrhbuisp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Provedor/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00016A70.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           Build environment           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version | 2.211.0                 |
| sdk         | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk        |
+-------------+-------------------------+
Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
sure your project is set up correctly.
fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[!] Error building the application - see the log above
Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
```

I've cleared the cache (yarn cache clean --force) , followed some suggestions I found here, but nothing has worked. Could someone please give me some guidance?